# `Extensions` field not shown in apollo graphql response data

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Here is a [reproducible example](https://github.com/stonecold123/typegraphql-test). Run `app.js` and navigate the playground at http://localhost:4000/graphql

You can run queries like:

```
query RecipeQuery{
  recipe(title:"Recipe 2"){
    description
  }
}
```

Problem:

I need debugging information from the `extensions` field in the response data. I'm talking about this `extensions` field:

```
  "data":{....},
  "extensions": {
    "tracing": {}
    "cacheControl":{}
  }
```

But in reality, I'm only getting the data field:

```
  "data":{....}
```

I have already enabled `tracing` and `cacheControl` in the apollo server config but the `extensions` field is still excluded in the response data. How can I get the `extensions` data back?

Here's how the apollo engine starts:

```
const expressApp = express();

const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    tracing: true,
    cacheControl: true,
    engine: false, // we will provide our own ApolloEngine
});

server.applyMiddleware({ app: expressApp });

const engine = new ApolloEngine({
    apiKey: "YOUR_ID",

});

engine.listen(
    {
        port,
        expressApp,
        graphqlPaths: [graphqlEndpointPath],
    },
    () => console.log(`Server with Apollo Engine is running on http://localhost:${port}`),
);
```

Dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-cache-control": "^0.1.1",
    "apollo-engine": "^1.1.2",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.2.2",
    "graphql-depth-limit": "^1.1.0",
    "graphql-yoga": "^1.16.7",
    "type-graphql": "^0.15.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could format the response from apollo with `formatResponse`.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  formatResponse: response => {
    console.log(response); 
    /* 
    ** { data } with informations such as queryType,
    ** directives ...
    ** I guess there is also the extensions key 
    */
    return response;
  }
});
```

[doc](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/monitoring/metrics/#high-level-logging)

Comment: It is done, apollo has rebuild their entire doc recently breaking a lot of urls ):