# I dont get extensions in response when using apollo server and graphql-tools

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-server

I have graphql server that serve as a gateway to serval grapql api servers and for some reason I dont get the custom fields inside the extensions in the response.

I am using `graphql-tools` mergeSchema function with `apollo-server` library.

```
const expressApp = express();

const server = new ApolloServer({
       schema,
       tracing: true,
       cacheControl: true,
    });
```

my response look something like that:

```
 "data":{....},
 "extensions": {
    "tracing": {}
    "cacheControl":{}
 }
```

If I query the graphql api without my gateway I am getting the custom fields in the extension part inside the response, But it seems that the `apollo-server` library or `graphql-tools` emit the custom fields from the extensions

Note: I tried to use the formatResponse like the answer below without success to get the custom fields in the extensions -

[`Extensions` field not shown in apollo graphql response data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367351/extensions-field-not-shown-in-apollo-graphql-response-data)

Thanks for any kind of help!!